# My java program is not putting the correct items into the output array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project where the computer takes two Strings from input in the command line. the first is a string of three cities, represented by its airport code, that is separated into commas and put in a 1D array. the 2nd is a list of the distances between each city that is made into a 2D array. I put them into their arrays properly and checked to make sure they don't have any issues. The final part that I am struggling with is that the user inputs is they want a list of all cities above or below a certain distance, what the distance is, and the city they want to start from. the method should be combing through all of the distances listed in the row representing that city, and put all of the city names into an array that would be printed. here is an example of the output:
user enters above the number, 1000, DFW
[ATL, BOS]
instead, with that input, im getting this:
[DFW, null]
Im not sure what I am doing wrong? i know its a lot but Im gonna put the code for the only method that isnt working properly below, meaning I don't believe its a problem with any input:

```
public static String[] searchDistance(int [][] distances, String[] cities, boolean isOver, int aDistance, String aCity){

 //confirms where city is in cities array
    int cityLoc = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        if(cities[i] == aCity){
            cityLoc = i;
        }
        else{
        }
    }

    //adds cities to arr
    int entry = outputArraySize(distances, cities, isOver, aDistance, aCity);      
    String[] arr = new String[entry];                                                                                
    int z = 0;

    if(isOver == true){
                                
       for(int j = 0; j < distances.length; j++){
          if(distances[cityLoc][j] > aDistance){
             if(distances[cityLoc][j] != 0){
                 arr[z] = cities[j];
                 z++;
             }
             else{
             }
          }
          else{
          }
       }
    }
 
 else if(isOver == false){
    for(int k = 0; k < distances.length; k++){
       if(distances[cityLoc][k] < aDistance){
          if(distances[cityLoc][k] != 0){
             arr[k] = cities[k];
          }
          else{
          }
       }
       else{
       }
    }
    return arr;
}
}
```

EDIT: here is the code I have to create the arrays needed and get the user input. all of the other methods besides searchDistance have been tested and shown to work properly:

```
public class TravelDistances {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //declare all the variables
        String[] cityInputArr = getCity(args[0]);
        int[][] distInputArr = getDistance(args[1]);


        System.out.println("Type true if you would like to search cities above a certain" +
                " distance or false if you would like to search cities below a certain distance:");
        boolean biggerOrSmaller = input.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println("Enter the distance you would like to search: ");
        int distInput = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the city you would like to start from: ");
        String cityInput = input.nextLine();
        String[] citiesOutput = searchDistance(distInputArr, cityInputArr, biggerOrSmaller, distInput, cityInput);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(citiesOutput));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(citiesOutput));
```

Comment: ca you show where you take an input, its hard to help without it

Comment: In this case, you'll want to add your input. That null value you are getting could be an issue with how the input value is getting declared